# What scipy statistical test do I use to compare sample means?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

Assuming *sample sizes are not equal*, what test do I use to compare sample means under the following circumstances (please correct if any of the following are incorrect):

**Normal Distribution = True** and **Homogeneity of Variance = True**

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(sample_1, sample_2)
```

**Normal Distribution = True** and **Homogeneity of Variance = False**

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(sample_1, sample_2, equal_var = False)
```

**Normal Distribution = False** and **Homogeneity of Variance = True**

```
scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(sample_1, sample_2)
```

**Normal Distribution = False** and **Homogeneity of Variance = False**

```
???
```

Comment: This seems more of a stats question. Have you tried Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the question here: [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110175/how-do-i-compare-sample-means-in-this-experimental-control-group-study)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Fast answer:

**Normal Distribution = True** and **Homogeneity of Variance = False** and **sample sizes > 30-50**

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(sample1, sample2, equal_var=False)
```

### Good answer:

If you check the Central limit theorem, it says (from Wikipedia): "In probability theory, the central limit theorem (CLT) states that, given certain conditions, the arithmetic mean of a sufficiently large number of iterates of independent random variables, each with a well-defined (finite) expected value and finite variance, will be approximately normally distributed, regardless of the underlying distribution"

So, although you do not have a normal distributed population, if your sample is big enough (greater than 30 or 50 samples), then the mean of the samples will be normally distributed. So, you can use:

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(sample1, sample2, equal_var=False)
```

This is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that 2 independent samples have identical average (expected) values. With the option equal_var = False it performs a Welch’s t-test, which does not assume equal population variance.